# How to access Virtual tables from MongoDB in Informatica

Tags: mongodb, informatica

I need to build a process in Informatica that uses Mongo collections as target.
Using the ODBC driver, and following [this guide](https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/5/IC_Winter2016_MongoDBConnectorGuide_en.pdf)I was able to represent a collection with 2 arrays as 3 tables (one main and one for each of the arrays).
**What works:** in the Designer view I can see all 3 virtual tables via the ODBC driver.

**What doesn't work:** when building a workflow at a session level, accessing the same ODBC driver does not show me these virtual tables, so I'm unable to work with them.

Any ideas for what I could be missing? Looking at the same [1](https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/5/IC_Winter2016_MongoDBConnectorGuide_en.pdf) guide I see on page 23 that in order to use the virtual tables in a task I should import the virtual tables (it's implied, not explicitly stated). Not sure what that means as I want to work with the driver to have access to the actual data rather than a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Sources and targets defined at the mapping level are an indication of their structure. In order to connect to them at the session level, you need to define a connection in workflow manager by choosing workflows -> Connections from the menu and then defining a new connection similar to the ODBC connection for your mapping